# valid assign for use array in C++

Tags: c++, pointers

i want to use dynamic memory but i don't want every time use plus the pointer to specific position. i always use
like

```
*(myPointer+position)
```

so i want to use like this
but i don't know that is valid or not..

```
struct profile{
    double x;
    double y;
    int intencity;
};
profile *asdf;
profile asdfe;
asdf=new profile[1024];

///here is my problem
asdfe=asdf[myposition];
```

my problem is that this {asdfe=asdf[myposition];} is valid or not?

Comment: Yes it is valid. However `asdfe` will hold a copy of whatever at position in `asdf` (auto generated copy constructor). What you changed in `asdfe` would not affect `asdf`

Comment: What about keeping track of the size used for acclocation, and check if `myposition` is valid for the array bounds before using it?

Answer (score 5):

`myPointer[position]` is equivalent to `*(myPointer+position)`.

Answer (score 4):

```
asdfe=asdf[myposition];
```

is equivalent to

```
asdfe=*(asdf + myposition);
```

Answer (score -6):

You can use

```
asdfe=*asdf[mypostion]
```

Although you may wish to make sure that `asdf[myposition]` is valid first. May I recommend creating a test application to test the concept? Pointers often behave similarly to arrays and as such the majority of compilers allow you to use them in such a way.

To prove the concept you can also use things such as

```
asdf[5] ->x = 7.3; //I made that up I don't have much context
asdf[5] ->y = 9.2;//That one too
asdf[5] ->intencity = 9001; //It's over 9000! Also it's spelled intensity.
asdfe=*asdf[5];

if(asdfe.x == 7.3)
    cout << "It worked!" << endl;
```

It should work something like that. As far as I'm aware. Like I said give it a try on a test application and feel free to have a play around with things you're not sure on.

Comment: `asdfe=*asdf[mypostion]` is wrong!

Comment: Pretty much *all* of the dereference work in this answer is wrong (`asdfe.x` appears to be the lone exception).